# iOS : apply affine transform to subview only

Tags: ios, objective-c, cgaffinetransform

I'm have a view-parent with one background image, which scaled to whole parent view. Also in view-parent i need to display some other views. So when i apply rotation to image :

```
[self.backgroundView setTransform:CGAffineTransformMakeRotation((CGFloat) M_PI)];
```

It rotates the whole parent view - so other subviews also rotated on 180 degrees

So, how can i apply rotation only to background view without affecting other views?

Comment: try to put a background view separated from the view inside, then when you rotate the background the other views will not be effected

Comment: unfortunately this solution is not preferable for me, may be i will change some previous architecture design solutions if there are no other ways

Comment: there is another way but it is not preferred, when you rotate the background view you can rotate the subviews the same speed and the opposite direction, it will seem like its not moving. its a dummy solution but could work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it sounds like your backgroundView has subviews that obviously would be transformed with parent, that's by design. What you need is to make your other views *siblings* of your background view. Make sure you're adding subviews to backgroundView's superview and not backgroundView itself.

Comment: Actually i do a mistake, but error was not here. Thanks for response - i more carefully check all and find solution...